# How to return value from asynchronous function in dll

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, std

My dll has asynchronous function which starts a thread and returns immediately. It accepts handle of event object (type `HANDLE`) which the thread signals when it is done. This works fine but how can I return result from the function that it passed and no error occurred? A simple bool type will do.

I am thinking of using GetLastError() kind of call to get result of last function but I am not really sold on this way. I also looked at std::future and std::async but I am not sure if I can use that in dll function!? Another option I thought about is to use `GetOverlappedResult`but that works usually with file i/o and I don't know if I can use this for a custom function that I have written.

Comment: take a look at [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)

Comment: if the thread accepts an arg (HANDLE), it may accept a pointer to a malloced struct (with the HANDLE, and the bool, and some char[42] for a small error message). The caller should only free when event signaled.

Comment: Can you pass a callback to "your" `DLL` function?

Comment: @Chad callback could eliminate the event, how would it help with returning a value?

Comment: Have the `DLL` call the callback function when the value is ready to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Chad is right callback is safe and easy way to do it

```
// DLL:
__declspec(dllexport) void (*callback_function)(DWORD ret)=NULL;

DWORD _stdcall thread_function(LPVOID p)
 {
 // do something ...
 if (callback_function) callback_function(some_return_value);
 }

// DLL usage
DWORD return_value1=0;
bool done1=false;
void callback_function1(DWORD ret)
 {
 return_value1=ret;
 done1=true;
 }

void main()
 {
 callback_function=callback_function1; // set callbak function for DLL
 done1=false;                             // invalidate return value
 // here call you DLL function
 for (;!done1;) Sleep(1); // wait for valid result ... also can add some timeout to avoid hang-ups
 // now in return_value1 is the valid return value
 }
```

also you can use waitforsingleobject instead

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I end up passing just a reference variable and that did the job!

Comment: yep but you should check for validity just to be sure because even if the tread is fast and stop almost immediately after creation you cannot take it for granted. sometimes threads get stuck for a while because of OS process management in that case you can read your return value before it is overwriten !!!.

Comment: you do not need any additional variable for it, just on start of the dll function set return value to some safe value (for example -1) and after thread creation wait until the return variable is different then this value. (Use Sleep so you do not get stuck!!!)  of course dll cannot return the same value at any occasion !!!

Comment: No, I read my referable variable only when the thread signal the event otherwise its value is meaningless.